# Selecting elements from list of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, slice

I have the following list of two arrays:

```
l=[array([16, 19]), array([24, 17])]
```

How one make new lists to have

```
#[16,24] and [19,17]
```

I have tried `l[0]` and `l[1]` but those just give me `[array([16, 19])]` and 
`[array([24, 17])]` respectively.

Comment: Can you make sure your list is n x  2 ? That is each item in the array contains exactly 2 integers?

Comment: Not sure it works with numpy arrays, but you can try `zip(*l)`

Comment: This also seems a lot like the transpose operation.

Comment: Indexing a list works the same whether the contents are lists or arrays. `l[0]` is just the first element of the list, not the first element of the all the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.tolist()` method from numpy

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np
l=[np.array([16, 19]), np.array([24, 17])]
print([i.tolist() for i in l])
```

Comment: Thanks just an small edit: print([i.tolist() for i in l[0]]) or print([i.tolist() for i in l[1]]) to complete the answer to my question

Comment: What is `Big`..?

Answer (score 4):

As I stated in the comments, this is the transpose operation.

```
import numpy as np
l=[np.array([16, 19]), np.array([24, 17])]

a, b = np.transpose(l)
print(a)
print(b)

# [16 24]
# [19 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `zip` and `map`:

```
list(map(list, zip(*l)))
# [[16, 24], [19, 17]]
```